# How to print out all constraints in Gurobi C++?

Tags: gurobi

I am using Gurobi now but the model turns out to be infeasible, so I am trying to print out all the constraints to see if I made mistakes. I know a few functions on how to print out the names of each constraint, but just couldn't find the final solution to print the constraints themselves(the mathematical expressions).

```
GRBConstr *c=0;
c = model.getConstrs();  

for(int i=0;i<model.get(GRB_IntAttr_NumConstrs);++i){
    cout << c[i].get(GRB_StringAttr_ConstrName) << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To debug a model, the best option is to write the model file in LP format.  In your example, add the code:

```
model.update();
model.write("debug.lp");
```

Then browse the file debug.lp in your favorite text editor.